# Is it possible to draw multiple filled circles in one path on canvas

Tags: performance, canvas, rendering

I am trying to make a performance optimization in the HTML5 canvas drawing code.
In particular I am looking at filled circles and lines. For lines I did optimization like that:
for every segment of the line it did the following:

- Begin path
- Move to
- Line to
- Close path
- Stroke

We got improvement once we opened path once and performed moveTo and lineTo for all points and after that closed path and did Stroke. Perf gain was pretty good.

I try to do similar thing for filled circles. Right now filled circles rendered in similar manner:
for every circle:Begin path, draw arc, set shape fill style, fill.
Test (http://jsperf.com/rendering-filled-circle/7 ) shows that rendering and filling multiple circles at once would be faster.
However, I will need to use moveTo before every call to arc otherwise I will get incorrect result: https://jsfiddle.net/gaeb9es8/1/
[image]
Here is what I expect: https://jsfiddle.net/j4b7jz03/1/
[image]

```
function render2(x, y, context){
            // x, y are arrays of points to render in a single path
            context.beginPath();
            for (var i=0; i< x.length; i++){
                //context.moveTo(x[i], y[i]);
                context.arc(x[i], y[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            }
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();          
        }
```

So the question is: is there a way to draw multiple filled circles of the same color in the same path on canvas and without using moveTo? moveTo is causing perf regression.

Comment: If all your circles share the same radius and color, you could draw it once on a buffer canvas then redraw the buffer with drawImage(bufferCanvas, x,y)

Answer (score 3):

Any other method would be awkward and yield less performance than `moveTo`.

**Remove the `closePath` in your second bit of code.**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
  var cx=Math.random()*canvas.width;
  var cy=Math.random()*canvas.height;
  ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,7,0,Math.PI*2);
}
ctx.fillStyle='red';
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: @VitaliyGanzha.  Just uncomment the `moveTo` and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/u0ysLzx0/  :-) Good luck with your project!